# How to make an effective crawler in Python2.7

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm crawling some webs of clothes to get their prices and their info of each product available but with my actual algorithm it takes days to finish and gets each different link of each product. For example if the product has 5 links for 5 colors it does the 5 links, and I have a database of 92k entries and only 5k products for example, like this:

https://i.gyazo.com/410d4faa33e2fbccf8979c5399856dd3.png

https://i.gyazo.com/b6118e67205d153272df001fb5efcfc8.png

Same product ID (so same product), but different link.

So I want ideas and how to implement them to improve that, for example I have the product ID so if I already visited one link that contains that ID I don't want to get again in it. And I want to crawl all the web but only visit the ones wich contains products... but I don't know how to implement that two ideas :/

Here is my code at the moment (too slow and with so many repeated):

```
import urllib
import urlparse
from itertools import ifilterfalse
from urllib2 import URLError, HTTPError

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urls = {"http://www.kiabi.es/"}
visited = set()


def get_html_text(url):
    try:
        return urllib.urlopen(current_url.encode('ascii','ignore')).read()
    except (IOError,URLError, HTTPError, urllib.ContentTooShortError):
        print "Error getting " + current_url
        urls.add(current_url)


def find_internal_links_in_html_text(html_text, base_url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
    links = set()
    for tag in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
        url = urlparse.urljoin(base_url, tag['href'])
        domain = urlparse.urlparse(base_url).hostname
        if domain in url:
            links.add(url)
    return links


def is_url_already_visited(url):
    return url in visited


while urls:
  try:
    word = '#C'
    current_url = urls.pop()
    print "Parsing", current_url
    if word in current_url:


        print "Parsing", current_url
        htmltext= urllib.urlopen(current_url).read()
        soup= BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

        [get the product info and save it into a sql database]

    html_text = get_html_text(current_url)
    visited.add(current_url)
    found_urls = find_internal_links_in_html_text(html_text, current_url)
    new_urls = ifilterfalse(is_url_already_visited, found_urls)
    urls.update(new_urls)

except Exception:
    pass
```

For example, in that crawler I use the word "#C" to know that it's a product page and get the info of it, but I don't know how to distinguish if that url has a product ID that I already visited, and I don't know how to avoid irrelevant urls, that's why the program is too slow and gets a lot of equal links

Thanks for the help, anything you could improve gonna be great ^^

Comment: Have you considered using [`scrapy`](http://scrapy.org/) instead?

Comment: Well I have 0 idea of scrapy :/ wouldn't know to translate it into scrapy and adding the rules I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org). My answer is based on its great features.

**Quoting your doubts:**

---

> I don't know how to avoid irrelevant urls

**Answer:** To avoid visiting irrelevant URLs you should use a Crawler with certain logic based on your use case. That said, you could use [CrawlSpider](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) and define your own [Crawling rules](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) where each Rule defines a certain behaviour for crawling the site so you won't visit irrelevant URLs.

Here is an example: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example

---

> ...but I don't know how to distinguish if that url has a product ID
>   that I already visited...

**Answer:** By default, Scrapy uses **`RFPDupeFilter`** as its `DUPEFILTER_CLASS` which is used to detect and filter duplicate requests. **`RFPDupeFilter`** filters based on request fingerprint using the `scrapy.utils.request.request_fingerprint` function.

This is a Scrapy log output sample for duplicated requests:

```
2015-11-23 14:26:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered duplicate request: <GET http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html> - no more duplicates will be shown (see DUPEFILTER_DEBUG to show all duplicates)
```

---

Here is a Scrapy tutorial if you haven't worked with it yet: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html